# MongoDB total index size proportionnal?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to know if the totalIndexSize is proportionnal to the number of document in a collection?

I would like to say yes however when I did some tests:

- For 101 elements: "totalIndexSize" : 294912
- For 55 elements : "totalIndexSize" : 131072

However for the 55 elements it stayed at 294912 for some time (then I used `db.collection.validate()` and `db.collection.reIndex()` and then I got 131072)

However when I do a ratio I have:
- For 101 elements 2919.92
- For 55 elements 2383.12

I wanted to try with 22 elemens but now I still get 131072

So I am a bit lost.

In fact I am doing those calculation to estimate (approximatively) the Ram I would need

> EDIT

I did some test by droping the collection and recreate it then fill it. The results are really strange. With 50, 100 and 200 documents the results for the size is coherant. However for the indexSize the value are the same even after a reIndex and validate. If the values are not going to the garbage collector I should a growing size of the index but here it stay the same....

```
"ns" : "hydb.profile",
"size" : 232504,
"count" : 200,
"avgObjSize" : 1162,
"storageSize" : 114688,
"nindexes" : 8,
"totalIndexSize" : 131072,
"indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.facebook.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.twitter.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.instagram.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.linkedin.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.github.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.google.userID" : 16384,
        "email" : 16384
},
"ok" : 1



"size" : 116228,
"count" : 100,
"avgObjSize" : 1162,
"storageSize" : 61440,
"capped" : false,
"nindexes" : 8,
"totalIndexSize" : 131072,
"indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.facebook.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.twitter.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.instagram.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.linkedin.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.github.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.google.userID" : 16384,
        "email" : 16384
},
"ok" : 1






"size" : 58099,
"count" : 50,
"avgObjSize" : 1161,
"storageSize" : 36864,
"capped" : false,
"nindexes" : 8,
"totalIndexSize" : 131072,
"indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.facebook.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.twitter.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.instagram.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.linkedin.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.github.userID" : 16384,
        "socialAuths.google.userID" : 16384,
        "email" : 16384
},
"ok" : 1
```

> EDIT 2

With 1000 profiles

```
"size" : 1162172,
"count" : 1000,
"avgObjSize" : 1162,
"storageSize" : 573440,
"capped" : false,
"nindexes" : 8,
"totalIndexSize" : 176128,
"indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 20480,
        "socialAuths.facebook.userID" : 20480,
        "socialAuths.twitter.userID" : 20480,
        "socialAuths.instagram.userID" : 20480,
        "socialAuths.linkedin.userID" : 20480,
        "socialAuths.github.userID" : 20480,
        "socialAuths.google.userID" : 20480,
        "email" : 32768
},
"ok" : 1
```

Regards

Comment: Are you removing documents from an existing collection to get those numbers, instead of creating those collections from scratch? Indices are probably not trimmed/garbage collected immediately, and/or they snap to certain pre-allocated sizes either way.

Comment: Yes I am removing them from existing collection. So you think it can be linked to this?